# How can I dynamically append and remove text for multiple class names?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have loads of elements of my page.

```
        <input class="userInput" type="text" />
        <img src="myPic.png" class="userImage" id="userImage" />
        <input class="firstNameInput someOtherClass" type="text" />
        <input class="lastNameInput" type="text" />
        ...etc...
```

However I need write a function to change the classes dynamically so that they end in "`Red`". e.g. "`userInputRed`","`userImageRed`". And then another function to revert them back.

I can select them all easily enough...

```
$('.userInput','.userImage'....)
```

..but I don't know how to alter their existing classes without writing lengthy code adding and removing classes for each element individually.

e.g. `$('.userInput').removeClass('userInput').addClass('userInputRed')`

Is there a way to do this using JQuery without so much repetition?

So something like this...

```
$('.userInput','.userImage'....).appendToClassName('red');
$('.userInputRed','.userImageRed'....).removeFromClassName('red');
```

Comment: you add the second class not remove the first class. because second override the first class in css automatically `$('.userInput').addClass('userInputRed')`

Comment: I get the feeling you should be assigning the same class to all your `input` elements, and giving each one a different `id` or `name` attribute.

Comment: Yes, it works. It's just that it involves a lot of repetition. I thought there might be a better way.

Comment: Why do you not simply toggle the class .red (and in your css you can target .userInput.red for example)

Comment: Why remove the class? Can't you just fix the issue with CSS Specificity?

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud Because I'm not smart enough to think of it. Thanks.

Comment: @MehdiBrillaud Tried it. Worked brilliantly. Please can you post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can toggle the class .red and target it in CSS with .userInput.red

Comment: Thanks. Obvious now you say it.